# Combining animation slider and buttons in R Plotly

Tags: r, plotly, slider, choropleth

I have faced some difficulties trying to make my choropleth map more interactive.
Few words about the sense of it all: I have two sets of countries' data for six years (I include only two years in example added). I want to make a graph with year slider and add two buttons to switch between my datasets. Thanks to manuals and questions here I made some draft but the data on the graph doesn't seem to update correctly when playing. For example, when I choose any set and click the button "Watch", data seems to change to the Set 2 in any case.
Maybe there is some tips about code order or something?

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(rnaturalearth)

df <- data.frame (country  = c("Argentina", "Canada", "USA", "Argentina", "Canada", "USA"),
                  year = c("2019", "2019", "2019", "2020", "2020", "2020"),
                  set_1 = c(12,34,103,14,36,125),
                  set_2 = c(8,34,82,9,35,120)
)

countries_graph <- plot_geo(df,
                            locationmode = "country names",
                            frame = ~year) %>%
  add_trace(locations = ~country,
            z = ~set_1,
            zmin = 1,
            zmax = 100,
            color = ~set_1,
            colors = "Blues",
            name = 'Set 1')  %>%
  add_trace(locations = ~country,
            z = ~set_2,
            zmin = 1,
            zmax = 100,
            color = ~set_2,
            colors = "Blues",
            name = 'Set 2')  %>%  
  
  layout(title = "Test choropleth map",
         updatemenus = list(
           list(
             type = "buttons",
             buttons = list(
               list(method = "restyle",
                    args = list("visible",list(TRUE, FALSE)),
                    label = "Set 1"),
               
               list(method = "restyle",
                    args = list("visible", list(FALSE, TRUE)),
                    label = "Set 2")
             ))
         )) %>%
  animation_slider(currentvalue = list(prefix = "Year: ")) %>%
  animation_button(label = "Watch")
countries_graph
```